# Appium: Not able to run the web mobile chrome browser script

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am getting below error when i ran the program.

[image]

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/DeploymentException
>
> at io.appium.java_client.android.ListensToLogcatMessages.(ListensToLogcatMessages.java:34)
>
> at mobile_web_browser_test.ChromeWebBroswerTest.main(ChromeWebBroswerTest.java:22)

Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException**

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)**
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)***
```

Platform: OS windows7,  jdk 1.8 version, Appium v1.8, Node v8.11, Seleinum-java 3.12, java client 6.0.1-Beats5, android sdk tools 25.2.5,android sdk platform-tools 27.0.1,android sdk build-tools27.0.3.

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: Seeing the same issue on Mac with Android, java-client-6.0.0 and selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified all dependencies in the build.gradle, as per the specific driver documentation.  In my case, I need to add `testImplementation group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '6.0.0'`, in order to instantiate an AndroidDriver instance.  (RemoteWebDriver, which I was using previously, did not require this depedancy.)